# Sorting by Columns with Wildcard Numbers and Writing Matching sets to File

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk, sed

I have used:

```
sort -k 1,2
```

to attain the following sorted dataset:

```
ATL, 03, 922, 145
EP, 05, 976, 76
EP, 06, 960, 85
WP, 21, 988, 46
WP, 22, 992, 46
```

How then would I write the sorted dataset (the first and second columns are joined in a sense), out to all different text files?

Column one will always contain ATL, EP, and WP. 
Column two will always contain arbitrarily assigned numbers.

What I also desire is to have all entries of ATL 03 be written out to one file of a static name, like storm1.txt; then all entries of EP, 05 be written out to another file of a static name, say storm2.txt.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F', +' '!(($1,$2) in a){a[$1,$2]=++c} {print > "storm"a[$1,$2]".txt"}' file
```

note that initial sorting of data is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have that sorted data in dataset.txt:

```
import csv
import itertools
import operator


with open('dataset.txt') as fin:
    infile = csv.reader(fin)
    for k,group in itertools.groupby(infile, operator.itemgetter(0,1)):
        with open('Storm_{}.txt'.format("_".join(k))) as fout:
            outfile = csv.writer(fout)
            outfile.writerows(list(group))
```